# Counting parent records by status, and applying another count by considering that one of the child element must have a particular child-status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables:
**Parent**:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SENT |
| 2 | CREATED |

**Child**:

| parent_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |

I have a following select statement:

```
select count(distinct parent.id)                                             as all,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'CREATED')    as new,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'SIGN')       as sign,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'SENT')       as send,
       
       --**what i want to add is**:
       count(distinct parent.id *if any child element has status 'a', if two child elements' status is 'a' then parent must be considered as +1*)  as with_child_element 
from "parent";
```

As you can see I have aliases as **all|new|sign|send**, and I want to add a new one (with_child_element) which will count parent records of which its any child element has status "1"

How to get the expected result? Any approach for solving this problem is considered

no idea how to group child elements without group by statement and inside an aggregate function (count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated EXISTS in the filter

```
select count(distinct parent.id)                                             as all,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'CREATED')    as new,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'SIGN')       as sign,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where parent.status = 'SENT')       as send,
       count(distinct parent.id) filter (where exists( 
               select 1 
               from Child c 
               where c.parent_id = parent.id and c.status ='a'
             )) as status_a
from "parent";
```

Comment: I think it works for me, thank you a lot, by the way for other condition I used 
count(distinct parent.id) filter (where not exists( 
      select 1 from Child c where c.parent_id = parent.id and c.status ='a'
)) as status_other
for now this is working too

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows using `left join` to child table :

```
select p.id,
       count(distinct p.id)                                        as all,
       count(distinct p.id) filter (where p.status = 'CREATED')    as new,
       count(distinct p.id) filter (where p.status = 'SIGN')       as sign,
       count(distinct p.id) filter (where p.status = 'SENT')       as send,
       count(distinct c.id) filter (where c.status = 'a')          as with_child_element 
from parent p
left join child c on c.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rnCDfbPk)